# Proving the time-evolution of momentum operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In QFT the evolution of momentum and field operators is given by $∂_0φ=i[H,φ]$ and $∂_0\pi=i[H,\pi]$.

Is it possible to derive these equations from the basic operator commutation relations or are they postulated?

Note: this is a follow-up to [Canonical quantization of quantum field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16141/canonical-quantization-of-quantum-field)

Comment: See the "Heisenberg picture". This is just the Schrodinger equation in a different point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic [canonical commutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) are equal time relations, which carry no information about evolution. In the operator formalism, the [Heisenberg equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) are postulated as evolution equations.