# Requirements for theory where Hamilton is the generator for time evolution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

#### Introduction

It is well known, that the Hamilton operator is the generator for the time evolution. In Heisenberg picture
$$
-i\ \partial_t \phi(x, t) = [H, \phi(x, t)].
$$
For a Quantum Field Theory, we usually start with the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\phi(x, t), \partial_\mu \phi(x, t))$, and then construct the Hamilton from there
$$
H(t) := \int d^3x\ \Big( \underbrace{\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_0 \phi)}}_{\pi(x, t)}\ \partial_0 \phi(x, t) -\mathcal{L} \Big).
$$
The other axioms besides how the Lagrangian looks like are the Canonical Commutator Relations for $\phi(x, t)$, $\pi(x, t)$.

#### Question

It is not at all obvious (at least for me), that given a Lagrangian, and the Canonical Commutation Relations, that the constructed Hamilton will be the time evolution generator.
**Is there any simple check given a Lagrangian to see whether it's constructed Hamilton will behave as the generator? What's one of the most accepted, fundamental requirement for Lagrangian for this property?**

Or we set Hamilton as the generator as an axiom, and then get the Canonical Commutation Relations?

I can even give counter examples, where this is not the case. For example, some **probably not valid theories**, like $\mathcal{L} \propto \phi (\partial_\mu \phi) (\partial^\mu \phi)$. This example is a Lorentz scalar, so in theory it can even be a good candidate, however, if the Canonical Commutator Relations hold, the Hamilton is not the time evolution generator.

#### Notes

- This question has been asked numerous times, but I have not seen satisfactory answers, only this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/360077/254794, but it does not answer why commutation holds like that. For other Noether Charges (momentum, internal symmetry charges), his/her answer explains this, but not for energy.
- I do not consider using the Poisson bracket $\rightarrow$ Commutator Relations quantization here as a good starting point. There are several quantum theories as far as I know, which do not have classical correspondence like that.

#### Related

- [Conserved charges and generators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358266/conserved-charges-and-generators) (I do not want to use Poisson Bracket as a starting point, not every quantum theory corresponds to a classical one.)
- [Why does the classical Noether charge become the quantum symmetry generator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74780/why-does-the-classical-noether-charge-become-the-quantum-symmetry-generator) (Also uses Poisson brackets, and one example Lagrangian to try to prove the general case.)
- [Connection between conserved charge and the generator of a symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137499/connection-between-conserved-charge-and-the-generator-of-a-symmetry) (Still just partial explanation as far as I saw.)
- [How a symmetry transformation acts on quantum fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418946/how-a-symmetry-transformation-acts-on-quantum-fields) (Related, but the answer does not answer my specific question.)

Comment: Are you sure your counterexample really is a counterexample? Can you show the calculation that made you think it's a counterexample? This may help potential answerers see what you might be missing.

Comment: Yes, I will outline the calculation steps here. $\pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_0 \phi)} = 2 \phi \partial_0 \phi$, so $\partial_0 \phi = 1/2 \phi^{-1} \pi$. Insert this form in $H$. We need to find $[H, \phi]$. Because $[\partial_i \phi, \phi] = 0$, $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, and from Commutator Relations $[\phi(y, t), \phi(x, t)^{-1}] = 0$, $[\pi(x, t), \phi(y, t)^{-1}] = i \delta^3(x - y)$, we can say (after some calculations), that $[H(t), \phi(y, t)] = i \phi(y, t) \partial_0 \phi(y, t) - 1/4 \delta^3(0)$. Correct me, if something is wrong.

Comment: A little bit more information about my calculation. As I mentioned, $[\partial_i \phi, \phi] = 0$, so $[Q(t), \phi(y, t)] = \int d^3 x [\phi(x, t) \partial_0 \phi(x, t) \partial^0 \phi(x, t), \phi(y, t)]$. Now, we insert $1/2 \phi^{-1} \pi$ for $\partial_0 \phi$ to get $\int d^3 x 1/4 [\phi(x)\phi(x)^{-1}\pi(x)\phi(x)^{-1}\pi(x), \phi(y)]$. Even if I made some error in my calculation, the correct result will still not give the generator for the Hamilton I think.

Comment: I made some minor mistakes in the calculation, sorry. The correct result is $[H(t), \phi(y, t)] = -i \partial_t \phi(y, t) + 1/4 \delta^3(0)$. So, my statement still holds even if I made some mistakes in my first calculation.

Comment: Have you tried a different ordering in attempt to remove that extra delta function?

Comment: No, I don't really know how would I order it differently. I think this example is not the main question here, but the general answer. Even if I didn't have a counter example, I would like to know in general.

Comment: We don't need to write $\dot\phi\sim\phi^{-1}\pi$, and in fact we *can't* do that because $\phi$ is typically not invertible. I posted a detailed general answer. The example $L\sim\phi(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi)$ can be traced through each step of the general calculation, but I didn't do that explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the *most* general formulation, but maybe it's general enough to answer the question. I'll use some abbreviations that are hopefully clear, like omitting the time-argument and writing $\partial\phi$ instead of $\partial_\mu\phi$. I'll write $\dot\phi$ for the time-derivative of $\phi$.

Start with any Lagrangian density $L(x)$ that can be expressed in terms of a field $\phi$ and its first derivatives $\partial\phi$, without any higher derivatives. Define the canonical conjugate$^\dagger$
$$
\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}
 \pi(x) := \frac{\delta }{\delta\dot \phi(x)}\int dy\ L(y)
\tag{1}
$$
and the Hamiltonian
$$
 H = \int dx\ \big(\pi(x)\dot\phi(x) - L(x)\big).
\tag{2}
$$
To define the quantum theory, impose the canonical equal-time commutation relations
\begin{gather}
 [\phi(x),\,\pi(y)]=i\delta(x-y)
\\
 [\phi(x),\,\phi(y)]=0
\\
 [\pi(x),\,\pi(y)]=0.
\tag{3}
\end{gather}
Equation (2) gives
$$
 [H,\phi(x)]=-i\dot\phi(x)
 +\int dy\ \big(\pi(y)[\dot\phi(y),\phi(x)]
 -[L(y),\phi(x)]\big).
\tag{4}
$$
The definition of $\pi(x)$ implies that last two terms cancel each other. To see this, use the identity
$$
 \int dy\ [L(y),\phi(x)]
  = \int dy\ \frac{\delta L(y)}{\delta\, \pl\phi(y)}[\pl\phi(y),\phi(x)]
 + \int dy\ \frac{\delta L(y)}{\delta \phi(y)}[\phi(y),\phi(x)].
\tag{5}
$$
(The derivatives of $L$ with respect to $\phi$ and $\pl\phi$ are formal, because $\phi$ and $\dot\phi$ are operators, but we can think of these derivatives as convenient abbreviations for a proper calculation that keeps track of the ordering of the operators.) The last term in (5) is zero. In the second-to-last term in (5), the commutator with the spatial derivatives of $\phi$ is zero, and the commutator with the time-derivative of $\phi$ cancels the second-to-last term in (4). Altogether, this leaves
$$
 [H,\phi(x)]=-i\dot\phi(x),
\tag{6}
$$
which says that $H$ generates time-evolution. (The sign-difference compared to the OP might be due to different sign-conventions.) We can also check $[H,\pi(x)]$:
$$
 [H,\pi(x)] = \int dy\ \big(\pi(y) [\dot\phi(y),\pi(x)] - [L(y),\pi(x)]\big).
\tag{7}
$$
As in (5), use the identity
$$
 \int dy\ [L(y),\pi(x)]
  = \int dy\ \frac{\delta L(y)}{\delta\, \pl\phi(y)}[\pl\phi(y),\pi(x)]
 + \int dy\ \frac{\delta L(y)}{\delta \phi(y)}[\phi(y),\pi(x)].
\tag{8}
$$
The time-derivative part of the second-to-last term in (8) cancels the second-to-last term in (7), and the remaining terms together with (3) and Euler-Lagrange equation of motion reduce equation (8) to
$$
 [H,\pi(x)]=-i\dot\pi(x).
\tag{9}
$$
Altogether, this confirms that $H$ generates time-evolution.

The $L\sim \phi(\pl\phi)(\pl\phi)$ example that was mentioned in the question satisfies the assumption that $L$ can be expressed in terms of $\phi$ and $\pl\phi$ alone, so the results (6) and (9) do hold in that example.

---

$^\dagger$ [Qmechanic's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/544909) correctly points out that the definition (1) is potentially ambiguous because it doesn't specify the order of the product (if any) of field operators on the right-hand side. The right-hand sides of equations (5) and (8) are abbreviations for more explicit identities that keep track of the order of the products of field operators, and since I didn't show the more explicit versions (which would be hard to do without specifying $L$), I didn't actually prove the cancellations that were claimed in the narration. So this answer is just an outline, not a complete proof.

Comment: Could you expand more why (5) is true? What does it really mean? Why $\delta L$ needs to be written there instead of $\partial L$? Also, could you specify when do you use Lagrange density, and when the full Lagrangian?

Comment: @Gabor Equation (5) is just a concise way of expressing the consequences of the identity $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$. If $L=AB$, then $\delta L/\delta A = B$, and so on. I wrote $\delta L$ instead of $\partial L$ only to avoid expressions like $\partial L/\partial\partial\phi$, which would be superficially ambiguous because the to $\partial$'s in the demoninator have different meanings. And oops - you're right. I was careless about mixing the lagrange density and its integrals. I'll come back soon and clean that up.

Comment: @Gabor  I edited the answer so that $L$ consistently denotes the lagrange *density*, with no implicit integrals over space or time.

Comment: Thanks you. Ok, I understand this answer intuitively, but still trying to check how can this be true a little more rigorously.

Answer (score 4):

1. OP's question about existence of quantization is very broad and is literally the topic of whole books and current research. For a general classical system, there is no proof that a consistent quantization exists.
   Although many partial results in e.g. [geometric quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization) and [deformation quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization) have been obtained.
2. The quantization procedure is not unique. When quantizing a classical model, there are often operator ordering ambiguities.
3. *OP's example:* OP considers the classical Lagrangian density
   $${\cal L}~=~ \frac{1}{2}\phi \dot{\phi}^2-{\cal V}, 
   \qquad 
   {\cal V}~=~\frac{1}{2}\phi(\nabla\phi)^2. \tag{A}$$
   The momentum becomes
   $$ \pi~=~\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\dot{\phi}}~=~\phi \dot{\phi} .\tag{B}$$
   It is not difficult to find the corresponding classical Hamiltonian density
   $$  {\cal H}~=~ \frac{1}{2}\phi^{-1} \pi^2+{\cal V}, \qquad H~=~\int\!d^3x~{\cal H}. \tag{C}$$
   The issue is now: *How should we order the quantum Hamiltonian density?*
   One possibility is
   $$  \hat{\cal H}~=~\frac{1}{2}\hat{\phi}^{-1/2} \hat{\pi}^2\hat{\phi}^{-1/2}. \tag{D}$$
   This is Hermitian. The time-evolution is
   $$\frac{d\hat{\phi}}{dt}~=~\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{\phi}, \hat{H} ]~=~\hat{\phi}^{-1/2}\hat{\pi}\hat{\phi}^{-1/2},\tag{E}$$
   or equivalently,
   $$\hat{\pi}~=~\hat{\phi}^{1/2}\frac{d\hat{\phi}}{dt}\hat{\phi}^{1/2}. \tag{F}$$

Comment: This does not answer the general question I think, only hints how we may get rid of problems in general, if possible. I'm assuming the ordering problem comes from the $\delta L \propto \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A} \delta A$ terms, because $\delta A$ may be on the other side, or inside $\mathcal{L}$. Am I right? Is it proven, that you can always find an ordering for which $H$ is the time evolution generator? For which kind of physical theories does this hold?

Comment: I updated the answer.