# Does the conserved quantity of the complex scalar field descend from a symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, noethers-theorem

The complex scalar field admits the conserved quantity
$$Q=i \int{d^3x (\Pi \psi - \Pi^* \psi^*)}$$ 
Is it the consequence of a symmetry of the system and the Noether theorem? If yes is every conserved quantity the consequence of a symmetry?

Comment: Looks like the charge for the $U(1)$ symmetry (even if without knowing the Lagrangian is difficult to tell). Usually the conservation laws are a consequence of symmetries, at least in Lagrangian systems.

Comment: You can find the symmetry transformation related to a conserved quantity by taking $$\delta \phi = i [Q,\phi].$$ This is discussed in detail in every introductory QFT book, e.g. Weinberg. See also here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137499/

Comment: Last subquestion is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451