# Connection between definitions of "conjugate momentum density" as "generator of displacement of the field" and as "Lagrangian partial derivative"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

I am reading [Jakob Schwichtenberg *Physics from Symmetry*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/326762666.pdf) where in [5.2](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/326762666.pdf#page=134&zoom=100,96,353)  conjugate momentum density $\pi(x)$ is defined as generator of displacement of the field itself (1):
$$
\pi(x) = −i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial Φ(x)}\tag{1}
$$

From that definition it follows that $[Φ(x), π(y)] = i\hbar δ(x − y).$

So far so good, but in [9.1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/326762666.pdf#page=225) we define (2)
$$
\begin{equation}
\pi(x) = \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_0 Φ(x))}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
$$
and still use $[Φ(x), π(y)] = i\hbar δ(x − y)$ that was derived from definition (1)

So my two questions

1. What is the connection between two distinct definitions of $\pi(x)$?
2. Why we can still use $[Φ(x), π(y)] = i\hbar δ(x − y)$ for the definition (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Ref. 1 is possibly a bit skimpy on details at the 2 placed mentioned by OP. (OP's issue already arise in QM, and transcribes in a natural way to QFT.) Let us stress the following facts:

- The momentum definition (2) is valid within the context of a classical Lagrangian formulation.
- It is then implicitly understood that we next Legendre transform to a classical Hamiltonian formulation with a fundamental Poisson brackets
  $$\{\Phi(x),\Phi(y)\}~=~ 0, \qquad \{\Phi(x),\pi(y)\}~=~ \delta(x-y), \qquad \{\pi(x),\pi(y)\}~=~0,$$ which we in turn quantize to a quantum mechanical formulation with a [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) that OP mentions.
- The momentum definition (1) is the Schrödinger position representation of this CCR. (There exists other representations of the CCR, such as e.g., the Schrödinger momentum representation, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86824/2451) Phys.SE post.)
- Moreover, the CCR implies that the momentum operator is the generator of position translations.

References:

1. J. Schwichtenberg, *Physics from Symmetry,* 2nd edition, 2018.

Comment: I think I get lost in what is postulated in the book (i e assumed "by definition") and what is deduced from math. It seems author of book postulated (1). From this it is deduced  CCR ([Φ(),π()]=ℏδ(−)) and then it is implicitly assumed that (2) is a equal (1) (i e generator of displacement).

I also found [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137499/connection-between-conserved-charge-and-the-generator-of-a-symmetry?rq=1) from which it follows that conserved charge Q is indeed a generator of displacement. Which confuse me even more because Q != () in (2).

Comment: So, you answer is describing a standard way to do QFT - with "first quantization" and "second quantization". But what I really try to understand is a way to do QFT from symmetry - described in the OP mentioned "Physics from Symmetry".
The author of the book do not use quantization nor path integral formulation to derive QFT. And so I try to unravel his approach.