# Why does the conserved quantity generate the transformation in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

If we have a lagrangian with a symmetry then we get a conserved quantity: $$Q=Q(p,q)$$ which is a function of the conjugate momentum and the coordinates.

If we move over to quantum mechanics then we promote $Q$ to an operator by promoting $p,q$ to operators but otherwise keeping $Q$ as the same functional form of $p,q$ (assuming no ordering ambiguities).Then if we want to apply the symmetry to a state $|\psi\rangle$ then we use the conserved quantity, $$|\psi\rangle\to|\psi'\rangle=e^{iQ}|\psi\rangle$$.

Why is the conserved quantity the  generator of the transformation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74780/2451

Comment: Looking at the symmetry transformation, have you seen why *Q* is conserved?