# Obtaining the generator for QFT from the classical field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem

Consider a classical theory on a manifold $M$, together with a smooth action $\theta: G\times M \to M$ of a Lie group $G$. Equivalently, one may regard $\theta: G \to \mathrm{Diff}(M)$. The Lie group action induces a Lie algebra homomorphism $V: \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak X(M)$. Elements of $V(\mathfrak g)$ are called as infinitesimal generators. For each $X\in \mathfrak g$, we have the Noether current $j_X^\mu$ and the Noether charge $Q_X$.

Quantizing the classical theory, we have a Hilbert space $H$. We also expect that the classical $G$-action should be translated to
a unitary representation $\hat\theta: \hat G \to U(H)$, and the associated representation $\hat V: \hat{\mathfrak g} \to \mathfrak u(H)$. Here, $\hat G$ and $\hat{\mathfrak g}$ are central extensions of $G$ and $\mathfrak g$, respectively.

**Question**: What is the most natural choice of $\hat \theta$ and $\hat V$?

I suspect that $\hat V(X)$ should be the quantization $\hat Q_X$ of the classical Noether charge $Q_X$, up to a factor of $\pm i$. Is this correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. I gather you have practiced on several simple examples? What detail puzzles you?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I want a "general" argument that justifies $\hat V(X) \sim \hat Q_X$, not based on simple examples. I also want that the argument is as rigorous as possible.

Comment: Maybe the level of runaway generality practiced in MSE is more appropriate. The standard routine argument is through deformation quantization, of course. I never suggested basing the argument on examples--I merely brought them up to help you concentrate your doubts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74780/2451